# Check date and insert sheet with columns and rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to automate a report at work. Data is fed into Google sheet from google form, at present I have automated part of the process see code below.

```
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();          //Gets the active spreadsheet.

var inputSheet = sheets.getSheetByName('Form');  //Gets sheet Form responses 1.

var lastRow = inputSheet.getLastRow();                       //Gets last row and stores it to variable lastRow.

var statSheet = sheets.getSheetByName('Nums');            //Gets numbers sheet.

var type = inputSheet.getRange('C' + lastRow).getValue();    //Gets column C which contains type of review i.e. compliment, comment or complaint.

var service = inputSheet.getRange('O' + lastRow).getValue(); //Gets column O which contains the service the review is assigned to.

var date = new Date(inputSheet.getRange('L' + lastRow).getValue());    //Gets column L which contains the date the review was submitted.
var month = date.getMonth();

var array = [["Befriending", "Comment", "B2"],["Befriending", "Compliment", "C2"],["Befriending", "Complaint", "D2"], ["Finance", "Comment", "B3"],["Finance", "Compliment", "C3"],["Finance", "Complaint", "D3"],

           ["Fund Raising", "Comment", "B4"],["Fund Raising", "Compliment", "C4"],["Fund Raising", "Complaint", "D4"],

           ["Home Help", "Comment", "B5"],["Home Help", "Compliment", "C5"],["Home Help", "Complaint", "D5"],

           ["I & A", "Comment", "B6"],["I & A", "Compliment", "C6"],["I & A", "Complaint", "D6"],

           ["Management Services", "Comment", "B7"],["Management Services", "Compliment", "C7"],["Management Services", "Complaint", "D7"],

           ["Toe Nails", "Comment", "B8"],["Toe Nails", "Compliment", "C8"],["Toe Nails", "Complaint", "D8"],

           ["Trading", "Comment", "B2"],["Trading  ", "Compliment", "C2"],["Trading  ", "Complaint", "D2"]  // Mutli-dimensional array containing the service, type of review and data range.
];           

for(m = 0; m < 12; m++) // For loop that iterates through m as an index less than 12 times.
{
  if(m === month){

  for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {

    collectingData(statSheet, service, type, array[i][0], array[i][1], array[i][2]); // Calling function to pass through arguments if conditions are met.
  }
}
}


function collectingData(statSheet,service, type, numbersService, numbersType, numbersColumn)
{

if(service === numbersService && type === numbersType)   // If service and type conditions are met, value is added to currentTotal

  {
  var currentTotal = statSheet.getRange(numbersColumn).getValue();
currentTotal++ 
statSheet.getRange(numbersColumn).setValue(currentTotal);
}
}
}
```

The above code works fine, however, what I need it to do is check if a month exists and if it doesn't create a new sheet for the data to be fed into.  I am relatively new to coding and don't know if this is possible?  I believe it is but how I write it out in code is puzzling me!

Comment: A couple of things, when you're getting the values from columns C and O, you are only retrieving one value, not the entire column, for that you need to change the `getValue()` method to `getValues()`. Also, what do you mean when you say you want to check if a month exists?

Comment: Thanks Alberto I'll make the amendment to this code :).  Regarding the check if a month exists.  Currently I have created a sheet called Nums which the data pulled from Form is stored in, what I want to do is have a new sheet created every month for that data to be stored in, so that we don't have to create a new sheet manually every month.

Comment: Additionally about the `getValues()`, it returns a 2D array with the values for the range. As for the month creation, there's a simpler way of doing that, you can use triggers to run your code once a month and it can create the new sheet when it does. If this sound like something that can help you please let me know and I'll explain how.

Comment: The trigger sounds like a great way of developing the functionality I am after.  I'd be grateful to hear more on this.

Comment: I'll post instructions as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

- Going to the code editor, clicking on the clock button that is
  between the "save" and "run" ones.
- This will take you to the trigger site, on the bottom right corner
  there will be a "add new trigger" button.
- Click it and you can select triggers that best suit you.
- For the one you want, in "event source" select "Time-driven"
- Then select "monthly" which day of the month and at what time of the day.

Pictures below to show example:

[image: trigger button]

---

[image: trigger settings]

---

Additionally, [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) is some documentation on triggers, in case you have any further questions.